# Autofill email and password with Selenium Chrome C#

Tags: c#, selenium

today the login page was changed https://fastinvest.com/de/investor/login and I am not able to fill in the email adress and password with selenium and chrome webdriver.

I usually use XPath, but the form fields will not be filled out. I also tried to execute a javascript but I couldn't make it.

It would be very nice if you could hlep me out how to set the email adress and password.

Comment: If you give us a little more code to work with we can help. What is the code that you are executing?

Comment: You should always be able to do this with Selenium. If Chrome Webdriver doesn't work, have you tried other web drivers? Bottom line, I've never been blocked from scraping or automating a site when using Selenium.

Comment: Also: CTRL+SHIFT+I to bring up the Chrome debugger. Inspect the HTML elements that you want. Likely the redesign has affected the XPath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two controls on that page that are located with a selector like `input#inputEmail`.  It is very likely your selector is finding the first instance of the input control, which is not displayed on the page.

This CSS selector should work for you: `input#inputEmail.login__input`.

Answer (score 2):

It would be better to identify if you'd add some sample code with this question.
How ever, your new code for login might be like -

```
IWebElement elem = driver.FindElement(By.Id("login-form"));

    elem.FindElement(By.Id("inputEmail")).Clear();
    elem.FindElement(By.Id("inputEmail")).SendKeys("test@gmail.com");

    elem.FindElement(By.Id("inputPassword")).Clear();
    elem.FindElement(By.Id("inputPassword")).SendKeys("test@gmail.com");

    elem.FindElement(By.CssSelector("button[type='submit']")).Click();
```

Comment: Hi Ali, I was using the same methods like you, but this doesn't work anymore with this website.

Comment: Id is unique for a page. So it is more convenient  than any other selector to find the element.

Comment: I've updated my code. First get the root element for form Id and then find the input element. I think it should work for you.

Comment: @StefanS I updated the code. Did you check and implement that?

Comment: @StefanS It is always better to find the parent element first and then find the child. It gives the efficient output for all browsers.